# can't find what's wrong with my php uploader

Tags: php, html, upload

I am trying to get a php upload script work. But I am not sure why the $_FILES appears to be empty array?  Can someone shed light on what went wrong on my script below?

## It supposes to upload arbitrary file into /var/www/test/ folder...

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

            $target_path = "/var/www/test/";
            $target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['myupload']['name']);

            if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myupload']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {

                echo '<pre>';
                print 'The $_FILES content is :';
                print_r($_FILES);
                var_dump($_FILES);
                echo '<pre>';
                print 'the target path is:' . $target_path;
                echo '<pre>';
                print 'the $_POST variable content is :';
                print_r($_POST) ;
                echo '<pre>';
                echo 'Your image was not uploaded.';
                echo '</pre>';

              } else {

                echo '<pre>';
                echo $target_path . ' succesfully uploaded!';
                echo '</pre>';

            }

        }
?>

<form method="POST" action="" enctype"multipart/form-data">
        Choose an image to upload:
        <br>
        <input type="file" name="myupload">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload(This_is_just_button_name_display)" name="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `<form>` is missing the `=` in `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: and on top of that it's simply blindly assuming success and blundering forward in spite of all the evidence PHP is trying to give you that things DID fail and you're utterly ignoring. **ALWAYS* check the `['error']` parameter in $_FILES before you do ANYTHING else.

Answer (score 0):

dont dump $_FILES I never dumped it and works fine for me.
try this code and put the php in another file and redirect form to it and add this line
at the end of the script

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="0;URL=samplehtml.html">
```

so the final code is:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

            $target_path = "/var/www/test/";
            $target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['myupload']['name']);

            if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myupload']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {

                echo '<pre>';
                print 'The $_FILES content is :';
                print_r($_FILES)
                echo '<pre>';
                print 'the target path is:' . $target_path;
                echo '<pre>';
                print 'the $_POST variable content is :';
                print_r($_POST) ;
                echo '<pre>';
                echo 'Your image was not uploaded.';
                echo '</pre>';

              } else {

                echo '<pre>';
                echo $target_path . ' succesfully uploaded!';
                echo '</pre>';

            }

        }
?>
```

its supposed to work now.